# How to return data from an UNION query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: video, video_category and video_category_join.

One video can have multiple `video_category` and a `video_category` can be associated in multiple videos: therefore the `video_category_join` table

**TABLE: video**

```
| video_id | title   | duration |
|-------------------------------|
| 12       | title12 | 190      |
| 24       | title24 | 190      |
| 78       | title78 | 190      |
| 34       | title34 | 190      |
| 91       | title91 | 190      |
| 88       | title88 | 190      |
```

**TABLE: video_category**

```
| video_category_id | name    |
|-----------------------------|
| 4                 | music   |
| 8                 | tv      |
| 5                 | black   |
| 2                 | politic |
| 1                 | movie   |
| 6                 | other   |
```

**TABLE: video_category_join**

```
| video_id | video_category_id |
|------------------------------|
| 24       | 4                 |
| 24       | 5                 |
| 78       | 4                 |
| 78       | 5                 |
| 88       | 1                 |
| 91       | 4                 |
| 91       | 1                 |
```

Given a `video_id`, i want to return 20 videos that have the same category as the `video_id`.

If the result set returns less then 20 videos, i want to be able to compensate by picking random videos until i get to 20 videos (the priority is always picking videos with the same category and, if necessary, random videos until i get to 20 videos).

So, if `video_id` = 24, the result set will return

```
| video_id |
|----------|
| 78       |
| 91       |
| 12       |
| 88       |
| 34       |
```

`video_id` 74 and 91 have the same category as the `video_id` 24, therefore are always on top. Then, to get upto 20 videos, the result set returns random `video_id` 12, 34 and 91.

I've asked many questions and found that i need a UNION type of query. Here's what i've build from the questions i've asked here... I'm almost there, i just need to complete the last query to get `video_id` 12, 88 and 34

```
SELECT video_id, title, duration
FROM (
    (
     SELECT v.video_id, v.title, v.duration, 1 AS preferred
    FROM video_category_join vc
    JOIN video_category_join vc2 ON vc2.video_category_id = vc.video_category_id AND vc2.video_id <> vc.video_id
    JOIN video v ON v.video_id = vc2.video_id
    WHERE vc.video_id = 24
    GROUP BY vc2.video_id
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 20
    )
    UNION
    (
    ...
    )
) AS t1
ORDER BY preferred
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas MySql version is 5.6.41-84.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `UNION ALL` between all the videos that have the same category as the video that you search for and all the rows of the table.
The unioned resultset's rows will differ on the value of the column `preferred`.
Then group by to keep only the minimum `preferred` for the common videos and finally sort by `preferred` and `rand()`:

```
select t.video_id, t.title, t.duration
from (
  select
    t.video_id, t.title, t.duration, min(t.preferred) preferred
  from (
    select distinct v.*, 1 preferred 
    from video v inner join video_category_join j
    on j.video_id = v.video_id
    where v.video_id <> 24
    and j.video_category_id in (
      select video_category_id
      from video_category_join
      where video_id = 24
    )
    union all
    select video_id, title, duration, 2 preferred
    from video
    where video_id <> 24
  ) t  
  group by t.video_id, t.title, t.duration
) t  
order by preferred, rand()
limit 20
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2wMa3KEKf349o1HgkzPYYr/7) (for limit 4).
Results:

```
| video_id | title   | duration |
| -------- | ------- | -------- |
| 91       | title91 | 190      |
| 78       | title78 | 190      |
| 34       | title34 | 190      |
| 12       | title12 | 190      |
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But does the first line needs to be repeated? Maybe there is something i don't see. I've created an example that works ok by removing the first line: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8APmc7HDKrLTT7qjiC8U1F/0

Comment: I've played around with your solution, nad came up with this shorter version. Do you see anything wrong with it? Thanks https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aonBcTpQ9ixiBStv7iuq9j/1

Comment: @Marco I can't find any problem with your solution, of course you have to test it with your data. But I thought that you wanted to get random rows from the 2nd query and this is why I chose the outer select in my solution. Your code will return the same rows each time you run it for the same search video. If this is ok with your requirement then fine.